# define compilation symbols in non "csproj" file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm using a lot of "compilation symbols" to control different things, for example logging.

```
    [Conditional("LOG_AAA")]
    public static void Warning(string s)
    {
        swLog.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay + " [Warning] " + s);
    }
```

At any time I can turn_on/turn_off "LOG_AAA" and control if certain logs need to be written.
I have many types of logs from different part of my program and I need often turn_on / turn_off some of them.

The issue is that every time I change any settings my "csproj" file updates and as I store it in repository I have to commit it.

The question is how to solve this problem?

- do not store "csproj" file in repository? but this file contains a lot of important things and so I'm afraid I have to store it in repository
- store "csproj" file in repository? then how to "extract" "compilation symbols" that I modify so often?

Likely "log4net" can solve my problem but I do not want to use it cause I like my pretty simple logging mechanism. I do not want to add one another library with a lot of stuff I'm not going to use so please do not suggest me just switch to "log4net". I agree that this probably will solve my problem and that I likely should switch to it but let's assume in this question that "log4net" (as well as other libraries) is not an option. Moreover this question is not only about logging, but about compilation_symbols that may be used for controlling anything (including logging).

Comment: *Compilation* symbols should be used to control *compilation* behaviour, not *execution time* behaviour. Use a `.config` file to store execution time settings. In the same way, uh, `log4net` does...

Comment: but I want to exclude certain methods calls at compile time because of perfomance requirements

Comment: The answers to this question can possibly help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1221343/4285